# passing multiple variables from an email to a php page via url

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send multiple variables via an email to a php page when the link is clicked on by the user, both the variables display on the email, however I am only able to pass one variable through the URL to the php page. I think this has something to do with my quotation marks

email code

```
$email = 'example@hotmail.co.uk';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_message =$message = $_POST['feedback'];
$date_added = date("y-m-d");


 $message = " $email_message,

    <a href='http://www.example.co.uk/email_feedback/feedback_result.php?name=$name&message=$email_message>Click HERE to Activate :)</a>";

$headers = 'From: <example.co.uk>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: <example.co.uk>';
$subject ='confirm account';


mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers,
  'example.co.uk');
```

Comment: your href='.....'    doesn't contain the closing quotation mark. Try to add that & then update the status please!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **$message** to:

```
$message = '$email_message,
    <a href="http://www.example.co.uk/email_feedback/feedback_result.php?name='.$name.'&message='.$email_message.'">Click HERE to Activate :)</a>';
```

Your *href* does not have a closing `"/'`. And hopefully that's the only problem.

Comment: the a href link is no longer clickable

Comment: thanks for your help i moved the email_message variable and it worked ill put my working code in the post

Comment: Glad I could "kinda" help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = $email_message. '
    <a href="http://www.joshpercival.co.uk/email_feedback/feedback_result.php?name='.$name.'&message='.$email_message.'">Click HERE to Activate :)</a>';
```